# Multiple Threads for Multiple Input Streams in iOS

Tags: multithreading, networking, ios7, xcode5

My iOS app needs to connect to multiple servers, up to five. When I connect sequentially it is slow, because a server response to the initial data query takes about three seconds. But if I open simultaneous connections, the responses get mixed together because they each come in two parts with the CRLF at the end of the second part. With two connections I end up with two inputs: partApartApartB and partB.

The listeners are added to the run loop when they are created. Can they be put into separate threads? And if so, would the listeners be isolated from one another so data from the multiple input streams does not mix?

The code I am using is common. My stream listener is:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            if (theStream == self.inputStream) {
                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;

                while ([self.inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [self.inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {

                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                        self->recieved = [self->recieved stringByAppendingString:output];

                        if (nil != output && [self->recieved hasSuffix:@"->"]) {
                            [self messageReceived:recieved];
                            recieved = @"";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            [self close];
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    } // end switch

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution. By putting each stream into a separate instance of a new class the two input streams were segregated from one another. I had previously used several variables to hold all the streams in a single class, a method that has worked for me in other environments but not in iOS.